# fopen alternative

Tags: php, fopen

I've got an simple php script, wich creates a file, add some content and closes it again. But my host disabled the fopen function. I was wondering how I could get around this. My host won't help me. This is my code:

```
$f = fopen($id."/adres.xml", "w");
fwrite($f, 'some content');
fclose($f);
```

I was wondering what alternatives there are. I've read many things about using cUrl, but to me that seems more like getting documents from other sites and using that, instead of creating a document (please tell me if this do is possible).

So, my question is, what are the alternatives to fopen (functions, etc).

Comment: I doubt it is not disabled in the context of path. It may be disabled in the term of URL Wrappers. You could give a try with the path instead of URL of xml file.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php you can try this as well ?

Comment: What's wrong with [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)? Have a look at the arguments, you may even append to existing files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//to write    
file_put_contents('path_and_filename','content');
//to read:
file_get_contents('path_and_filename');
```

If you want to append to the file:

```
file_put_contents('path_and_filename' , 'content' , FILE_APPEND );
```

You can also lock the file:

```
file_put_contents('path_and_filename' , 'content' , LOCK_EX );
```

Take a look at the links below:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php