# PHP String to input stream without fopen

Tags: php, stream, fopen

Is there a way to convert a string to an inputstream without using fopen? Since fopen isn't allowed on the server because of corporate policy I'm kinda struck.

I was using this:

```
$string = "abcdef";
$stream = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $string,'r');
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why isn't fopen allowed on the server? More specifically, what are the ramifications? Can you not read/write/create files on the server via php? Also, I found a stackoverflow question where someone had success with file_put_contents...may be worth a shot.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881774/fopen-alternative

Comment: FYI: data:// is not binary safe.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this works, haven't tested it, but what if you do this:

```
  ob_start();
  include('files/path');
  $file_string = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: sorry but this won't do. This just gives you back a string. I need a stream specially for reasons I didnt mention, but the core of the problem is this.