# Get string from HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html

A few days ago, I asked how I can get the content of another website with cURL. I managed to get this working. Now I want to get the some dates from the html that are stored in

`<td class="table_day"></td>`

I believe I could do this with DOMDocument or DomXPath. 
this is the code that I tried:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$lis = $dom->getElementsByClassName("table_day");
```

OR

```
$classname="table_day";
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

I managed to get the code with some help, but when I open my console in safari, I get the **Internal Server Error** message. I think this is because fopen is not enabled on my localhost and/or my webserver.

Is there another way to get a string from html code using php?

This is the code I want to get the different dates from:

```html
<tr class="table_date_row">
  <td>Week: 11</td>
  <td class="table_day">Maandag 09-03-2015</td>
  <td class="table_day">Dinsdag 10-03-2015</td>
  <td class="table_day">Woensdag 11-03-2015</td>
  <td class="table_day">Donderdag 12-03-2015</td>
  <td class="table_day">Vrijdag 13-03-2015</td>
  <td class="table_day">Zaterdag 14-03-2015</td>
  <td class="table_day">Zondag 15-03-2015</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you are sure `fopen` is at fault, you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881774/fopen-alternative

Comment: I think you should use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and [DomCrawler component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).. Here is [an example](http://www.ymc.ch/en/webscraping-in-php-with-guzzle-http-and-symfony-domcrawler) how to do the similar thing..

Answer (score 0):

(1) Read HTML with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
(2) Parse the dates with [RegularExpressions / preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://whatever");
preg_match_all('|table_day">(.*)<\/td>|', $html, $result);
print_r($result[1]);
```

Comment: This seems my logical solution as well

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument isn't that cool way to get HTML, it is best fit with XML instead; as XML are usually well written and in most cases HTML code are messy and improper.

You can read your file with any method you like, ex: cURL, file_get_contents or sometimes you can use wget if you are on linux server.

To get specific info from HTML structure is best handled by RegularExpression. There are lot many examples available online for the same.